# Sub string search with solr

Tags: search, solr, drupal-7, full-text-search

I am trying to use ReversedWildcardFilter in solr.

I have refred 
[this example](http://solr.pl/en/2011/10/10/%E2%80%9Ccar-sale-application%E2%80%9D-%E2%80%93-solr-reversedwildcardfilter-%E2%80%93-lets-optimize-wildcard-queries-part-8/).

I am trying with below xml code.

```
`<analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="'"
            replacement="" replace="all" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
            stemEnglishPossessive="0" />
    <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
            maxPosAsterisk="2" maxPosQuestion="1" minTrailing="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0"/>
  </analyzer>`
```

And When I am trying with below query it is returning no result set.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/new_core/select?q=*pal*&wt=json&indent=true
```

I don't know where things go wrong.
It should work

Comment: That is the longest analysis chain I have ever seen :)
It is very long and it has conflicting areas,
Can you please clean it up, removing all the commented parts first?

Second, what is your real requirement ?
Why do you need wildcard search? On which Fields( short/big ect)
Which kind of wildcard search you are trying to optimize?

Comment: Comments now removed.
Requirements : Let say there is word "drupal" and if user search with "pal" without quotes it should give result. But as of now its not working like this. That's why i tried with wildcard search.

Comment: charFilters go before the tokenizer. Remember that wildcard searches skips most of the (if not all) of the analysis chain. Since you're using edgengramfilter, just searching for 'pal' should match 'drupal' with your current chain. Use the "Analysis" tab under the collection admin to see how the content is processed for each step. The analysis chain for querying might also be important to why you're not getting a hit.

Comment: Thanks, @MatsLindh I tried your suggestions but they did not work.edgengramfilter did not work that's why I go with ReversedWildcardFilter.

Comment: But _why_ didn't it work? You probably want NGramFilter and not the _Edge_ version, so you get tokens generated for all variations inside the string as well, and not just from the beginning..

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank @MatsLindh. Solr is new for me so that's why I may be confused.